# Dismiss Popover using Unwind Segue in Xcode Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller, xcode4.5, uistoryboardsegue

I am using Xcode 4.5 and the new iOS 6 feature to unwind segues. I am presenting a navigation view controller inside a popover which is presented programmatically from a bar button item:

```
- (IBAction)configChartTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (self.popover.isPopoverVisible) {

        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    } else {
        UINavigationController *chartConfigNavigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GrowthChartNavigationController"];

        ConfigChartTypeViewController *configChartTypeViewController = (ConfigChartTypeViewController*) chartConfigNavigationController.topViewController;

        self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:chartConfigNavigationController];
        self.popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500);
        self.popover.delegate = self;

        [self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Next to this method I have defined a target to unwind the segue (i.e. dismissing the popover)...

```
- (IBAction)cancelConfig:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    //
}
```

... and connected it to a cancel button in the navigation view controllers's navigation bar.

Connecting the cancel bar button to the cancelConfig button worked fine in Xcode.

However, when running the code, nothing happens when clicking on the Cancel button despite Xcode 4.5 should be supporting dismissing popovers when unwinding segues (according to the release docs).

What did I miss?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? I'm stucked here too

Comment: Dan, unfortunately I did not find a solution to this problem yet. I am still using plain-old delegation and hope that Apple will fix this issue soon. Please let me know when you have found a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unwind segues use runtime searching by first asking the parent view controller to walk up the chain of view controllers presented via segue until it finds the correct unwind method. But there is no chain here since the popover was created programmatically rather than with a popover segue.

No callbacks are occurring since there is no segue link back to the parent view controller. Unwind segues are an abstracted form of delegation, so this would be similar to forgetting to set the delegate and not receiving any callbacks.

The solution is to create the popover with a segue in Interface Builder rather than create it programmatically with the `configChartTapped:` method.

**Steps:**

First, control-drag from the bar button item in the *presenting* view controller to the *presented* view controller and select the popover segue:

[image]

In the *presenting* view controller, implement `prepareForSegue:` to grab a reference to the popover controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue
                 sender:(id)sender {
    self.popover = segue.popoverController;
}
```

Then implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` to restore 
the show/hide behavior similar to `configChartTapped:`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if (self.popover.isPopoverVisible) {
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Finally, in Interface Builder, set the correct popover content size  for the *presented* view controller:

[image]

This will allow you to unwind to `cancelConfig:` when tapping the cancel button from the popover, and also show/hide the popover when tapping the button that presents it.

Comment: This is an easier way check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247727/unwind-segue-doesnt-dismiss-adaptive-popover-presentation-when-not-modal